# 404 Page Error When Referencing XML file through Flash on Same Domain

Tags: xml, flash

I have this flash element that used to work before but now it's not showing up. If I go to the URL with the XML path: http://young-folks.com/header1_cs3.swf?xmlPath=http://young-folks.com/xml/CubeSlides.xml it shows up as 404 Page Not Found, yet the individual SWF and XML links work fine.

I tried uploading these exact same SWF and XML files on another server and it seems to work perfectly: http://scrapgoldsell.com/header1_cs3.swf?xmlPath=http://scrapgoldsell.com/xml/CubeSlides.xml but I need it to work on my other server young-folks.com, why is it not working on young-folks.com but working perfectly on scrapgoldsell.com? Please help, I've tried searching everywhere but couldn't find a solution.

Thank you!

Comment: Try this: http://young-folks.com/header1_cs3.swf?xmlPath=xml/CubeSlides.xml  I also answered why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like sort sort of URL rewriting that is changing the path from the SWF to another location.

When you try this:

```
http://young-folks.com/header1_cs3.swf?xmlPath=http
```

it loads the swf but not the XML slides.

```
http://young-folks.com/header1_cs3.swf?xmlPath=http://
```

this does not.

What you can do is remove http:// and use the following that works because the SWF can load the XML using the relative path on the server.

```
http://young-folks.com/header1_cs3.swf?xmlPath=xml/CubeSlides.xml
```

Comment: Mind finalizing/selecting the answer :) Also you need to contact your admin about that URL rewriting.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the issue on the site with your help. I marked your answer as finalized. :)